# How to update total price of completed order in woocommerce?

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

is it possible to update total price of a completed order in woocommerce.

Suppose I have ordered a item whose order no is 2010 and total price is $1200

now I want to update total price to $2000 and order no would be same i.e 2010